# Tomcat 7 manager-text with curl and self-signed certificate not working

Tags: tomcat, curl, deployment, tomcat-manager

So, I have an interesting dilemma here.  I have a Tomcat 7 server setup with the manager application.

The exact command [within reason] I am running is as follows:

> curl -k --upload-file ~/[build.directory]/ROOT.war
>   https://[ManagerLoginName]:[ManagerLoginPwd]@[fqdn-serverName]:8443/manager/text/deploy?war=ROOT.war&path=/&update=true

I am getting FAIL - Invalid context path  null was specified

If I run the `/manager/text/reload?path=/` it reloads the context, the same as if I run the undeploy command, it undeploy's correctly.  It just seems that I cannot deploy using:

`deploy?war=ROOT.war&path=/&update=true`

The syntax is correct, I'm kind of stumped as why this would not deploy.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions based issue at the firewall.